# how to create image preview when using rich:fileUpload for the image upload

Tags: ajax, jsf

I cannot figure out the workable way to preview image when rich:fileUpload is used to upload it. As it is a legacy project, I cannot use anything else to upload it and just need to preview image.

I added the following:

1. Tag h:graphicImage to display image preview.
2. Attribute uploadData="#{fileUploadBean.data}"
3. Tag a4j:ajax inside tag rich:fileUpload to react to filesubmit event.
   Html is as follows.

```
<td>
     <h:graphicImage id="image-preview" value="#{fileUploadBean.data}" height="100px" width="100px"/>
</td>
<td style="padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 3px;">
     <h:panelGroup id="uploadGroup" rendered="#{(not empty cc.attrs.doc.data) or (cc.attrs.showLoadButton ne 'false')}">
          <rich:fileUpload id="upload#{cc.attrs.num}"
          uploadData="#{fileUploadBean.data}"
          fileUploadListener="#{cc.attrs.bean.documentUploaded}"
          acceptedTypes="#{cc.attrs.uploadtype}"
          ontyperejected="alert('Для этого документа можно загрузить только #{cc.attrs.uploadtype} файл');"
          sizeExceededLabel="Разрешены файлы не более 15 мегабайт"
          rendered="#{cc.attrs.isRendered}"
          allowFlash="false"
          immediateUpload="true"
          maxFilesQuantity="1"
          listHeight="100%;"
          clearAllLabel=""
          uploadLabel=""
          addLabel=""
          deleteLabel=""
          clearLabel=""
          doneLabel="Загружено"
          disabled="#{cc.attrs.readonly}"
          render="uploadpanel#{cc.attrs.num} #{cc.attrs.render} designFileLoad"
          limitRender="true">
             <f:attribute name="doc_type" value="#{cc.attrs.doctype}"/>
             <f:attribute name="doc_id" value="#{cc.attrs.doc.hashCode()}"/>
             <a4j:ajax event="filesubmit" execute="@all" render="image-preview"/>
        </rich:fileUpload>
```

The bean FileUploadBean is as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadBean {

    private Object data;

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

However the preview does not work this way, the data is null. I cannot figure out how to get and display data of files to be uploaded after they are selected but before they are uploaded.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_mediaOutput.html